# Use a list file to extract a second list from a master file (and comment out some lines)...HOW?

Tags: text-processing

I have two files: `master.tbl` and `sites.lst`

The file `master.tbl` is a list of sites, with their port configurations, port names, IP addresses, etc.  There are lines containing site descriptions, comments, etc., but they are irrelevant.  The lines containing the site configurations are arranged thusly, and are delimited by spaces.:

```
{server} {SITE NAME} {port name} {configuration flags}
```

The port names consist of the site name in lowercase, a dash, a "P", and the port number.

Example:

```
server01 HAWAII23-USR hawaii23-P1 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
server01 HAWAII23-ADM hawaii23-P2 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
server01 HAWAII23-ADM hawaii23-P3 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
server01 HAWAII23-USR hawaii23-P4 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
```

`sites.lst` is a list of sites that I need to search the `master.tbl` file for.

I need to comment out (insert a `#` at the beginning of the line), and extract the server name and port name (into a file named `stoplist.lst`) of every line that meets ALL of the following criteria:

1. contains any site name listed in `sites.lst`
2. contains "-ADM "
3. has a port number higher than '2' (example: `hawaii23-P3`)

In the above example, the `master.tbl` file would look like this:

```
server01 HAWAII23-USR hawaii23-P1 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
server01 HAWAII23-ADM hawaii23-P2 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
#server01 HAWAII23-ADM hawaii23-P3 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
server01 HAWAII23-USR hawaii23-P4 blah-configuration-blah-arguments
```

...and `stoplist.lst` would contain (assuming `HAWAII23` is in `sites.lst`):

```
server01 hawaii23-P3
```

`master.lst` is almost 300,000 lines, so doing this manually would be...bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z[$0"-ADM"]++;next}
{p=$3;sub(/.*-P/, "", p); if ($2 in z && p > 2)
{print $1,$3 > "stoplist.lst"; $0="#"$0}}1' sites.lst master.tbl
```

This reads `sites.lst` first and sets `$0"-ADM"` (that is the site name + the string `-ADM`) as an index of the array `z`. It then processes `master.tbl` extracting the value after `-P` in the 3rd field as `p` and, if the conditions are met (2nd field is in `z` and `p` greater than 2) it prints 1st and 3rd fields to `stoplist.lst` and comments the line out.
Note that it doesn't edit the file in-place but you can always redirect to another file and overwrite the original if everything is OK (though with a recent `gnu awk` you have the option `-i inplace`).

Comment: This worked beautifully.  Thank you so much.